# Hangman in BlueJ

Tags: bluej

I'm trying to code hangman in BlueJ using a string-based game board. I have the game board as a string in a different class and I'm trying to call it over in my main class so it prints after the desired word for guessing has been entered. Every time I run the code, it prints  Gameboard@ with random numbers and letters instead of the actual hangman game board. In the code above I'm putting the void main from my Hangman class and then the code for the game board from  my Gameboard class.

Hangman Class:

```
`public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Player 1, enter a word! ");
    word = in.nextLine();
    wordTwo = word;
    System.out.println("Your word is " + wordTwo);
    System.out.println("Press (p) when you're ready to continue!");
    start = in.nextLine();
    wordChars = wordTwo.toCharArray();
    if (start.equals("p"))
    {
        CLS();
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Wait what? Restart the program and try typing 
        the key that ACTUALLY STARTS THE GAME!");
    }
    Gameboard board = new Gameboard(); //Line of code that's supposed to 
                                         call the game board.
    System.out.println(board); //Line of code to print game board.
    while ( trap == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Player 2, will you guess a word(w) or a 
        character(c)?");
        System.out.println("Type 'e' to exit");
        wordOrChar = in.nextLine();
        if (wordOrChar.equals("w"))
        {
            guessWord(guessWord);
        }
        else if(wordOrChar.equals("c"))
        {
            guessChar(guessChar);
        }
        exit = in.nextLine();
        if (exit.equals("e"))
        {
            trap = 2;
        }
    }
}`
```

Gameboard Class:

```
public String board(String board)
{
    board = (" -------------" + "\n" + "|             |" + "\n" + "              |" + "\n" + "              |" + "\n" + "              |" + "\n" + "              |" + "\n" + "              |" + "\n" + "              |" + "\n" + "              |" + "\n" + "---------------"); 
    return board;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your gameboard class it is expecting a parameter passed to it(String board), yet when it is called there is no parameter being passed. Remove the required parameter and all should be OK. Failing that, rename your class variable to gameBoard and return it, instead of board. :)